# Consume specific SDK dlls in Nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-6.0, .net-standard, dotfuscator

I'm compiling my code with `net6.0`.

One of my depends projects, compiled with `netstandard2.0`, is using a Nuget package with DLLs for `netstandard2.0` and `net5.0` (and also `netstandard1.1` and `net45`).

In the output folder, I see it takes the `net5.0` DLL.

**How can I choose to take the `netstandard2.0` DLL?**

---

The requirement is for *Dotfuscator*, because it looking for the `net5.0` Runtime, according to that `net5.0` DLL. The question should be asked about *Dotfuscator*, but I'm in the middle of a research to understand the *Dotfuscator* better, so in meanwhile I'm asking about the Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `netstandard2.0` or any of the `netstandard` targets are actually compiled to `netstandard`. `netstandard` isn't a runtime, it's a specification of the API's that are shared between runtimes such as `net5`, `net45`, etc, allowing you to use the same codebase over different runtimes. Depending on  which runtime you compile for, the `netstandard` library will be compiled to that.

Basically, since you are compiling your application in `net6`, your `netstandard2.0` library is also compiling as a `net6` library. It then will use the correct dependencies (the `net5` one) to compile.